# make sure input start with 9344 and has 13 digits all up

Tags: javascript, forms, input, digits

Is there away to make sure that all digits inside a INPUT#barcode start with 9344 and has 13 digits in it?

I really need to do this before the form is sent, as I want to use a required as I have a red thumb inside the input box if they have not filled it in.

demo @ http://www.vipcashback.com (use to be incard.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression should do the trick:

```
if (/9344\d{9}/.test(val) {
  // matches 9344 followed by 9 more digits
}
```

where 'val' is $('#barcode').val()

Comment: but how do I make it if they put 9343 it stays invalid

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  The regular expression above won't match 9343.
I did realize that although it's not entirely necessary, we probably want put to the starts with and ends with characters:
/^9344\d{9}$/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form validation plugin(like [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)).

And use a regex rule on your input.

Your regex rule is: **9344\d{9}**